# Is there an app/solution to quickly send text snippets/links/images from Windows pc (clipboard) to your iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, file-sharing

I constantly have the problem that I want to push a text snippets/links/images quickly from my Windows pc to my iPhone, without it being plugged or on the same Wi-Fi.

Every time, it seems to be a hassle. I send myself emails, or whatsapp messages.

There must be a solution. Does anyone know a remedy for this?

Comment: https://www.pushbullet.com/

Comment: that i did so far ... i created a secondary telegram account and send content there iPhone <-> PC
actually works quite well, though a workaround

Answer (score 1):

Modern Macs and macOS have a feature built called [AirDrop](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203106) which lets you push said content from a Mac directly to your iPhone. No such feature exist for Windows PCs.

There is no straightforward and native mechanism build into Windows to push Text Snippets, Links and Images from Windows PC to an iPhone. The only resort is to indirectly use an app which can be accessed on both platforms.

To keep things simple, you can login to [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com) using a Web browser on Windows PC and paste links, text snippets and images into Notes app. The pasted content can be instantly accessed in Notes app on your iPhone.

Both Windows PC and iPhone need to be connected to Internet, not necessarily to the same Wi-Fi. (both of them can be technically anywhere in the world)